# how to take screenshot of UIImageView in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I want to take the screenshot of one imageview. And set that screenshot as an image in another imageview. I struck in this process. please help me.

Answer (score 5):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size);
 [imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
yourSecondImageView.image = viewImage;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take the UIImage property of the UIImageView you have, and assign it to the other image view you want.

Comment: sorry i forgot to write in detail. I have an imageview with some image. Then i rotate that imageview 90 degree. Now i wants screenshot of rotated image. even i try some coding i got only non-rotated imageview rather than rotated image.

Comment: Instead of screenshotting a rotated imageView, search for ways to actually rotate the bitmap data in an UIImage.